# How do I enable the WIFI radio of an HP ProCurve 420ww Access Point?

Tags: hp, wifi, access-point, hp-procurve

So based on [this old question of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/833795/how-can-i-configure-a-hp-procurve-420ww-access-point) I figured out that I can reset the access point and access it using telnet through a wired Ethernet connection.

I have set a new password, I have set up the Ethernet connection so it doesn't conflict with my main router, and most importantly **I have specified the country because this turns the WIFI radio on - except it didn't...**

I have the [Getting Started Guide](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/59906005-e1.pdf) and also the [Management and Configuration Guide](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/59906006-1004.pdf) as well as [this official FAQ](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02593858#soft4). They all indicate that the WIFI radio is turned on when I have specified the country.

--> Why does the status still say "Radio Status : Disabled"?

```
HP ProCurve Access Point 420#show system 

System Information
============================================================
Serial Number         : TW413QB09X
System Up time        : 0 days, 0 hours, 4 minutes, 3 seconds
System Name           : Enterprise AP
System Location       : 
System Contact        : Contact
System Country Code   : AT - AUSTRIA 
MAC Address           : 00-0D-9D-F6-65-78
IP Address            : 192.168.1.3
Subnet Mask           : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway       : 192.168.1.1
VLAN State            : DISABLED
Management VLAN ID(AP): 1 (U)
IAPP State            : ENABLED
DHCP Client           : DISABLED
HTTP Server           : ENABLED
HTTP Server Port      : 80
HTTPS Server          : DISABLED
HTTPS Server Port     : 443
Slot Status           : 802.11g
Radio Status          : Disabled
Software Version      : v2.2.5
SSH Server            : DISABLED
SSH Server Port       : 22
Telnet Server         : ENABLED
Max Telnet Session    : 4
Serial Port           : ENABLED
Reset Button          : ENABLED
SSID Number Supported : 8
============================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ you linked it has to bet set and saved:

> Q: How do I set the Country Code to enable the radio?
>
> The correct Country Code must be set for the country in which you
>   operate the access point so that it uses the correct authorized radio
>   channels for wireless network devices.
>
> The North America product, J8130A, comes with the Country Code
>   pre-configured; the worldwide product, J8131A, does not. The radio is
>   disabled if the Country Code is not set. Once the Country Code is **set
>   and saved**, the radio is enabled.
>
> If you are using the worldwide product, J8131A, before configuring
>   radio settings on the access point, you must first use the CLI to set
>   the Country Code. You can display the available country codes in the
>   CLI by using the country? command from the Exec level. After a Country
>   Code is entered the country command is removed from the Command Line
>   Interface (CLI). If an invalid Country Code has been entered, reboot
>   the access point by pressing the reset button for at least five
>   seconds. This restores the factory default settings.

Comment: Thank you Brian - I had done a reset on the device and then as a very first thing *set and saved* that country code, then confirmed that the `country` command is no longer available, as per this documentation. So it looks like I did things right *and yet it still has **status:disabled*** which is the odd thing leading to my posting here...